# C# how to convert data types inside a conditional

Tags: c#, if-statement, typeconverter

Hi i make a c# little program what request to the user 2 numbers and return a value but in case what the user input a double number, the program can will solve the problem with a if else statement buit i dont know how to do.

this is the code.

```
using System;

namespace c_
{
class suma
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N1;
        int N2;
        int suma;
        Console.WriteLine ("Digite el numero");
        N1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine ("Digite el otro numero");
        N2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        suma = N1 + N2;
        Console.WriteLine ("Total " + suma); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `double` everywhere?

Comment: yeah but i need to make a if else statement where i convert the input values to double .

Comment: No, you don't need and if/else at all - just use all `double` values and `double.Parse` - or possibly use `decimal.Parse` instead, as `decimal` arithmetic is likely to be less surprising...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, learn some basics. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx) you can read about Double. But that's your solution:

```
        int suma = 0;
        int n = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            double number;
            if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
            {
                // Tell user input is invalid
            }
            else
            {
                suma += (int) number;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total " + suma);
```

If you really need to tell user his input type then:

```
int suma = 0;
int n = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int intNumber;
    double doubleNumber;
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intNumber))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el numero");
        suma += intNumber;
    }
    else if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out doubleNumber))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el otro numero");
        suma += (int)doubleNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        // Tell user input is invalid
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Total " + suma);
```